# How to link two objects so that when changing one the other also changes, but they stay separate objects?

Tags: modifiers, linked-data

I have 2 objects that I want linked to have a modifier apply to A with B. I don't want to apply the modification yet so I would like to link them together so that when scaling A, B will scale the same way. Is this doable through a parrent type relationship perhaps?

In my case I want to have the cilinder object be scaled the same way as I would scale the mesh under it. If I widen or lengthen the mesh I want the cylinder to mirror that exactly, in this case it's for a boolean operation so that might matter also in what is possible to do.

[image]

Comment: Select both of them and scale? or simple Parenting works. or  parent both objects to an empty .

Comment: Right that would work however if I have the top one set to invisible and don't want to keep going back and forth to make it visible ? It's not really a solution to what I want to do, it's a workaround ....

Answer (score 0):

Seems that setting the parent of the cilidner to be a mesh does exactly what I needed ... Scaling is applied and the cilinder can be made invisible.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Geometry Nodes. I crated a node setup, where the cylinder on top of the box only scales in X-direction if the box is scaled:

[Demo video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/l9BTuQdLfjc)

Node tree:

[image]

To do this do the following:

- select the cylinder
- Change to geometry editor
- Add new geometry node to the cylinder
- Drag an drop the cube from the scene tree into the geometry node editor. This will create a "Object Info" node with reference to the cube.
- Add other nodes according to what is posted here.

You can restrict the axis of scaling by routing only one or more axes between the "Separate XYZ" and the "Combine XYZ" nodes. Connecting all three axis will scale along all axes, interchanging the axes will scale the cylinder into another direction - say Z when scaling the cube into X